# Outside of a JSON File, what is a better way to store a long dictionary of key value pairs in my website

Tags: javascript, html, web

I'm not a super experienced web developer but I've been working on a for fun project as a resource for a gaming community I'm in. The website compares the frame data of characters in a fighting game to determine whether moves are safe or not. Currently, I'm storing the frame data of these moves in large key value pairs within a JSON format and parsing the information. The code ends up looking extremely messy and it feels like the way I'm doing this is very amateur. See code example below:

`const character1 = '{"Name": "character1", "Jab1": 2, "Jab1_OS": -14, "Jab2": 2, "Jab2_OS": -16, "Jab3": 3, "Jab3_OS": -29, "Ftilt": 5, "Ftilt_OS": -13, "Uptilt": 5, "Uptilt_OS": -18, "Dtilt": 5, "Dtilt_OS": -15, "DashAttack": 6, "DashAttack_OS": -17, "FSmash": 15, "FSmash_OS": -22, "UpSmash": 9, "UpSmash_OS": -20, "DSmash": 5, "DSmash_OS": -31, "Fair": 16,"Fair_OS": -12, "Nair": 3, "Nair_OS": -2, "UpB": 3,"UpB_OS": -20,"Bair": 6,"Bair_OS": -2,"Dair": 5,"Dair_OS": -11,"Upair": 4,"Upair_OS": -3, "Grab": 6, "SideB": 12, "SideB_OS": -16, "NeutralB": 17, "NeutralB_OS": -23, "DownB": 21, "DownB_OS": 0}';`

`const char = JSON.parse(character1Json);`

This way I can easily call `char.Jab3` for example to get the frame data for that specific move.

Another annoying aspect about the way this is stored is that I have to have 2 separate numbers for each move so writing out each individual character's frame data becomes a long tedious project.

For example there's two separate numbers for `char.Jab3` and `char.Jab3_OS`

What is the best way to do this for a fairly amateur developer who doesn't have a ton of web experience?

Comment: I suggest you learn about RDBMS instead. Yes, it's boring and unsexy, but gaining an understanding of "real" (sorry!) databases is essential, I feel. But it really does pay for itself, quite literally, many times over...

Comment: Have a look at the data structure and try putting multiple numbers in an array (easier than object) held under a key for the move, not multiple keys for the same move. You probably will want to learn about [destructured assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) as well.

Comment: Also, if you are including frame data inline within a JavaScript file, you don't need to parse it (JSON is generally source code compatible with JavaScript). If you are holding it separately is another matter. You could improve the post by including more information about what you will accept for now for the sake of simplicity - and reword the question as to how you are handling data for different characters. At the moment it's lacking in detail to answer specifically.